# URL for facebook app goes to "Page not found" - has this changed?

Tags: facebook, url

I built an app a couple of months ago and now I cannot get to it via the URL.

I am using

[`http://www.facebook.com/#!/apps/application.php?id=\[APPLICATION_ID\]`](http://www.facebook.com/#!/apps/application.php?id=%5BAPPLICATION_ID%5D)

Does anyone know if this has recently changed?  I have looked at other app URLS and they seem to have the below format:

[`http://apps.facebook.com/[APPLICATION_NAME]/?ref=ts`]

What do I need to do in order to get mine working again?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook deleted all app pages and forced developers to make a generic page for their apps. Details here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/01/how-to--migrate-your-app-profile-page/

If you missed their deadline, you just lost your page. Maybe your app gets the new URL when you create the new page.

Comment: ok, thanks but Im not sure I understand.  I did see something about this a few weeks ago but didn't think it applied to my app as I do not have any likes or photos or anything listed on the page that I need to migrate.  Therefore I just need to know the 'new target Page'.  Where has the app gone if it no longer has a page? It doesn't seem to provide any details on this.  Many thanks,

Comment: Ok, I have created a new app page via the facebook developer advanced settings.  However, Im still without a URL to the app.

Comment: What kind of app did you create? For my page tab app, going to the new page I created reveals a button on the right (near the like button) that says "Go To App."

Comment: I can't see a "Go to app" link.  However I have a "store" link which links to my app.  Strange...  http://www.facebook.com/pages/Test-FWS-Storefront-Community/220032744764981

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this again. Facebook is doing a POST request to your app page. In my case I was only serving it for GET's and this caused the `Page not found` error.